# Regex removing empty line at the end

Tags: regex, pcre

Given this string

```
z


h
```

I am trying to remove all empty lines (not white spaces, only empty lines) with this regex `^$[\r\n]+` as show in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6RvjQG/1)

However there is a single empty line remaining after the `h`

Any help in removing that last empty line will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with the multi-line option.

```
/^[\w\W]*?([\r\n]+)$/
```

matches the end; including the newline on the last line with content.
https://regex101.com/r/hWeKrm/1

To match all empty lines:

```
/^$/mg
```

https://regex101.com/r/sSJtI1/1

Comment: Thanks Sander. In your demo, I do not see how do I get the `z` and `h` without any empty lines, either on top, below or in between them

Comment: Your title indicated you wanted to remove newlines only on the end. To get just empty lines /^$/gm https://regex101.com/r/sSJtI1/1

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\n/mg
```

Replace with empty string.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CYPzYY/1/)

In Python for example:

```
>>> s = """
...
... z
...
...
... h
...
...
... """
>>> s_new = re.sub(r'^\n', '', s, flags=re.M)
>>> s_new
'z\nh\n'
>>> print(s_new)
z
h

>>>
```